# switching regulator's interference

Tags: switching-regulator

I'm a new user of switching regulator.
It's not clear for me to understand how to choose one or another switching regulator
I also try to figure out, what're the parameters in datasheet, which characterize the interference generated by the component and also the maximum of interference, that the component could undergo.
I have to find a switching accept 12V and generate 18V

Comment: Hi Joe! While I really like your approach – understanding what you need to know about a class of devices to help you choose correctly – you're neither giving us enough info on your application to give you a specific guideline for how to choose in your case, nor is "OK, I need a 12V –> 18V SMPS, what do I need to look for" *narrow enough to fit a single book*, let alone a StackExchange answer. The interference aspect seems to be of importance to you, so that's much more specific, and one could focus on that, if one didn't get the feeling that you're lacking the SMPS & EMI basics to understand…

Comment: … so maybe, a bit of literature or introductory videos could help you better than we could? http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/analog/powermanagement/support-community.page
TI.com also has extensive training material on things like EMI compatibility of SMPSes, but again, that's advanced, and basically expects that you're an EE (because understanding interference requires understanding both the physics behind its origin, propagation and pickup, as well as the technological effect on the receiving end of interference).

Comment: To augment the other comments, you could do a lot worse than read through "Switching Regulators for Poets". http://www.linear.com/docs/4120

Answer (score 2):

Here is example of interference generated by a switchreg.

Assume the switchreg controls 1 amp input current, and switches that current in 10 nanoseconds.

Assume, nearby, is a 1cm by 1cm loop of your sensitive circuit such as ADC or opamps or radio. This loop is flat, such as on a PCB.

We model the interference as a long straight wire in the same plane as the loop.

Assume the current being switched (1 amp turning on or off in 10 nanoseconds) is in the long straight wire, located 1cm from the loop.

The equation we use is

$$Vinduce = [MU0 * MUr * Area / (2 * pi * Distance) ] * dI/dT$$

Manipulating this, we get Vinduce = 2e-7 * Area/Distance * dI/dT,
or

Vinduce = 2e-7 * 1cm * 1cm/1cm * 100Million amps/second

Vinduce = 2e-7 * 1e-2 * 1e+8

Vinduce = 2e-9 * 1e+8

Vinduce = 0.2 volts

In an ADC with 5 volt input range, a 0.2 volt error is 4 parts per 100, 4% error.

The math also tells us, given Vinduce ~~ 1/distance, at 1 meter distance, the Vinduce drops only 100X from 0.2volts to 2 milliVolts.

Planes in your PCB will improve on this, for switching speeds at 10 nanoseconds.
Slower switching speeds ----- 100 nanoseconds ----- may be more troublesome, as Skin Effect provides little shielding but the dI/dT is 10X smaller.

[Caution] This equation is only accurate for infinitely long wire. A switchreg is not an infinite source, but when the loop dimensions are similar to the distance between loop and wire, the equation is quite useful and accurate to within a "log" factor.